# Help to create grid for a table

Tags: magento2, grid, table

I need to create a simple adminhtml grid to a table. I went through several tutorials on the internet and none worked.

It's a simple table with an ID, text1, text2, created_at and updated_at columns.

Anyone can help me with a simple tutorial that works ?

Thank you !

Comment: Have you seen https://mage2gen.com/? Experiment with model tab and look at files generated

Answer (score 0):

Check this link to create a grid in admin: https://meetanshi.com/blog/create-admin-grid-magento-2/

In the given link you will find both the method to create the admin grid.

- Using the Block
- Using the UI_Component

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, I tried this tutorial yesterday before asking the question but unfortunately did not work.